# Linear Algebra - Finding the basis of a column space

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a basis for the column space of the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}1&-2&0&0&3\\2&-5&-3&-2&6\\0&5&15&10&0\\2&6&18&8&6\end{bmatrix}$. What is the rank?

What I've done so far is I found ref(A) which is: $\begin{bmatrix}1&-2&0&0&3\\0&1&3&2&0\\0&0&1&1&0\\0&0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$

How do I figure out the column space of this matrix now that I've found out the ref?

Also, I found the rank of this matrix to be 3.

Comment: It is the span of the pivot columns of the matrix. The first three columns (of the original matrix) will span the column space.

Comment: @DavidPeterson based on the ref(A), you find out that the first three columns of the original matrix is the column space of the matrix?

Comment: Yes. You need not go to reduced echelon form. Any echelon will identify the pivot columns.